# cd command usage in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, command, cd

Hey I'm designing my shell in C as a school project.But I'm stuck with cd command usage in this shell .

Here is the related explanation:

> `cd <directory>` — change the current default directory to `<directory>`. `
>
> If the
>       `<directory>` argument is not present, report the current directory.
>
> If the directory
>       does not exist an appropriate error should be reported. You need to support relative and
>       absolute paths. This command should also change the PWD environment variable.

I get path like this:

```
const char *path = getenv("PATH");//get the system's path
```

Here is the main part that I'm planning to fill out:

```
  else if(strcmp(argsexec[0], "cd") == 0) {
            if(argsexec[1]== NULL){
            system("pwd");//Reporting current directory.
            }
            else if(strcmp(argsexec[1],"..") == 0);
            /**HERE Go to upper directory.          
            }
            else {
            /**HERE Case for cd <directory> go to that directory
            }
        }
```

How can these HERE parts be achieved?

Comment: Well, just use the path you have and replace the end portion with nothing after the second to last slant, eh? That should do for a (bare-bones) up one directory cd command.

Comment: `getenv("PATH")` returns the current value of `$PATH`, the search path for executable commands. It has nothing to do with the "path" that should be an argument to the `cd` command. And you shouldn't need to treat `".."` as a special case. `man chdir`

Comment: Normally, [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) with no argument changes directory to the directory specified in `$HOME` (and that is not necessarily the directory specified in the password database as the home directory, obtainable via `getpwuid()` etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use these function to implement your function:

```
   char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
   char *getwd(char *buf);
   char *get_current_dir_name(void);
   int chdir ( const char *path );
   int fchdir ( int fd );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want it easy, just execute `chdir(argsexec[1])` (and you do not need to handle the '..' case separately).

When you want it more complicated, you have to handle symbolic links. E.g. when there is a `/lib -> /usr/lib` symlink, users might expect after `cd /lib/somedir && cd ..` to be in `/` but not in `/usr`.  To handle this case, you will have to keep track of the logical path and to implement `..` traversals.